# How can one align input tex-files (written with TikZ) by a defined point?

Tags: tikz-pgf, technical-drawing, engineering, stanli

My code:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{stanli}
\usetikzlibrary{angles,
                quotes
               }

\newcommand*\coordinateSystem{\draw
                                [<->] (7, 0) node[right] {$x$} -|
                                      (6, 1) node[above] {$y$};
                              \draw
                                [->] (6, -.5) arc (-90 : 180 : .5);
                             }

  \begin{document}

    \input{virtual_displacement_system}\\[\baselineskip]
    %contains:
    %\begin{tikzpicture}[trim left = { (0, 0) }]
      %%the points and their names
      %%A
      %\point{begin}{0}{0};
      %\notation{1}{begin}{$A$}[above = 50pt];
      %%B
      %\point{middle}{2.5}{0};
      %\notation{1}{middle}{$B$}[above = 50pt];
      %%C
      %\point{end}{5}{0};
      %\notation{1}{end}{$C$}[above = 50pt];
      %%the beam
      %\beam{2}{begin}{end};
      %%the support
      %\support{1}{begin};
      %\hinge{1}{begin};
      %\dimensioning{1}{begin}{middle}{1.5}[$l$];
      %\dimensioning{1}{middle}{end}{1.5}[$l$];
      %%the load and their names
      %%M
      %\load{2}{begin};
      %\notation{1}{begin}{$M$}[above right = 10pt];
      %%G
      %\load{1}{middle}[90];
      %\notation{1}{middle}{$G$};
      %%F
      %\load{1}{end}[-90];
      %\notation{1}{end}{$F$}[below right];
      %\coordinateSystem
    %\end{tikzpicture}
    $M$ und $G$ seien bekannt. Gesucht ist $F$ und die Auflagerreaktionen. Freischnitt:\\[\baselineskip]
    \input{virtual_displacement_free_body_diagram}\\[\baselineskip]
    %contains:
    %\begin{tikzpicture}[trim left = { (0, 0) }]
      %the points
      %\point{begin}{0}{0};
      %\point{middle}{2.5}{0};
      %\point{end}{5}{0};
      %%the beam
      %\beam{2}{begin}{end};
      %%the load and their names
      %%A_x
      %\load{1}{begin}[180];
      %\notation{1}{begin}{$A_x$}[left = 30pt];
      %%A_y
      %\load{1}{begin}[-90];
      %\notation{1}{begin}{$A_y$}[below right];
      %%M
      %\load{2}{begin};
      %\notation{1}{begin}{$M$}[above right = 10pt];
      %%G
      %\load{1}{middle}[90];
      %\notation{1}{middle}{$G$};
      %%F
      %\load{1}{end}[-90];
      %\notation{1}{end}{$F$}[below right];
      %\coordinateSystem
    %\end{tikzpicture}
    Virtuelle Verschiebungen:\\[\baselineskip]
    \input{virtual_displacement}
    %contains:
    %\begin{tikzpicture}[trim left = { (0, 0) }]
      %%the points
      %\point{begin}{0}{0};
      %\point{end}{5}{0};
      %the beam
      %\begin{scope}[dashed]
        %\beam{2}{begin}{end};
      %\end{scope}
      %%the displaced points
      %\point{delta_begin}{.5}{.5};
      %\point{delta_end}{5.5}{1};
      %%the displaced beam
      %\beam{2}{delta_begin}{delta_end};
      %%virtual displacements
      %\dimensioning{2}{begin}{delta_begin}{0}[$\delta y$];
      %\dimensioning{1}{begin}{delta_begin}{.5}[$\delta x$];
      %\draw
        %[dashed] (delta_begin) -- (5.5, .5);
      %%angle between the beam and displaced beam
      %\coordinate (A) at (5.5, .5);
      %\coordinate (B) at (delta_begin);
      %\coordinate (C) at (delta_end);
      %\pic[draw,
            %angle radius = 45mm,
            %angle eccentricity = .9,
            %"$\delta \varphi$"
           %] {angle};
      %\coordinateSystem
    %\end{tikzpicture}

  \end{document}
```

The result:

[image: result]

The input files: [virtual_displacement_system](https://www.upload.ee/files/7824764/virtual_displacement_system.tex.html), [virtual_displacement_free_body_diagram](https://www.upload.ee/files/7824760/virtual_displacement_free_body_diagram.tex.html) and [virtual_displacement](https://www.upload.ee/files/7824755/virtual_displacement.tex.html).

Is there a way to align all three pictures by the point `A` in the above picture? In short:

[image: wished result]

Thank you for your help and effort in advance!

Comment: Yes have a look at the key called  `trim` in the manual. You can give a point say the origin to be trim point.

Comment: Hello @percusse! Thank you for your comment! With `trim left` in every picture (`virtual_displacement_system`, `virtual_displacement_free_body_diagram` and `virtual_displacement`) all three pictures aligned by their left border. It isn't what I wish. I do something wrong. Maybe you can provide more help? Or should I edit my question and build in the information provided by you? Thank you for your help and effort in advance!

Comment: try `trim={(0,0)}` or any other point not `trim left`

Comment: Hello @percusse! Thank you for your comment! With `\begin{tikzpicture}[trim = { (0, 0) }]` I receive an error `I do not know the key '/tikz/trim'`. Do I something wrong? I also not find the command `trim` in the `TikZ` manual (`trim left`, `trim right` and `trim lowlevel` yes). Maybe you can provide more help please? Thank you for your help and effort in advance!

Comment: Instead of posting links to some ad-filled annoying download page, can't you add the code directly to your question?

Comment: Also, @percusse's memory might have failed him a bit here, there is no `trim` key, as you say yourself. However, `\begin{tikzpicture}[trim left={(0,0)}]` does what I think you're after. (Or `\begin{tikzpicture}[trim left=(A)]`, if you have a coordinate named `A` in each diagram.)

Comment: @TorbjørnT. My memory has no shame :( That's right indeed

Comment: @Torbjørn T.! Thank you for your comment! I edited my question. With `\begin{tikzpicture}[trim left = { (0, 0) }]` in each picture all three pictures aligned by their left border like I wrote in my above [comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/408129/how-can-one-align-input-tex-files-written-with-tikz-by-a-defined-point#comment1020207_408129). What do I wrong? Maybe you can provide more help please? Thank you for your help and effort in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is another one of those cases where I can't explain why things fail, but I can point out how to make it work.

Instead of using `\\[\baselineskip]` (which is frowned upon anyway), start a new paragraph by adding an empty line of code before and after the diagram. (If you're always adding `\\[baselineskip]` you're doing the wrong thing anyway, the correct approach would I think be to use `\documentclass[parskip=full]{scrartcl}`, and start new paragraphs with empty lines.)

Consider first this simplified example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{showframe} % to indicate text area bounds
\usepackage{parskip} % set zero parindent and some parskip

\newcommand\demodiagram[1]{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[trim left=(a)]
\coordinate (a);
\fill (a) circle[radius=2pt];
\draw [<->] (a) +(-#1,0) -- +(2*#1,0);
\end{tikzpicture}}
\begin{document}
Here we have paragraph breaks before and after the diagrams.

\demodiagram{1}

\demodiagram{2}

And it works as expected.

But this\\
\demodiagram{1}\\
does not\\
\demodiagram{2}\\
work.
\end{document}
```

The output looks like this:

[image: result of above code]

So you can see that this fails with the structure you've used, i.e. linebreaks with `\\`.

## Complete example with your code.

In the following code block I implemented the same for your code, but I also demonstrate a second approach, which is to add a line similar to

```
\useasboundingbox (-2,2.5) rectangle (7.5,-1);
```

at the start of each `tikzpicture`. When added at the very beginning of the diagram, this lets you manually set the bounding box. To have multiple diagrams aligned, you just need to make sure that the x-component of the first coordinate is the same in all `tikzpicture`s. The other values need to be adjusted separately for each diagram.

This approach is less convenient than `trim left`, but has the benefit that the diagrams wont protrude into the left margin. (Depending on the x-value you choose for the leftmost coordinate.)

```
% note the parskip=full parameter which disables paragraph indentation
% and sets some vertical space between paragraphs.
\documentclass[parskip=full]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{stanli}
\usetikzlibrary{angles,
                quotes,backgrounds
               }

\newcommand*\coordinateSystem{\draw
                                [<->] (7, 0) node[right] {$x$} -|
                                      (6, 1) node[above] {$y$};
                              \draw
                                [->] (6, -.5) arc (-90 : 180 : .5);
                             }
\usepackage{showframe}

\begin{document}

   On this page \texttt{trim left} is applied.

   % \input{virtual_displacement_system}
    %contains:
    \begin{tikzpicture}[trim left=(begin)]
      %%the points and their names
      %%A
      \point{begin}{0}{0};
      \notation{1}{begin}{$A$}[above = 50pt];
      %%B
      \point{middle}{2.5}{0};
      \notation{1}{middle}{$B$}[above = 50pt];
      %%C
      \point{end}{5}{0};
      \notation{1}{end}{$C$}[above = 50pt];
      %%the beam
      \beam{2}{begin}{end};
      %%the support
      \support{1}{begin};
      \hinge{1}{begin};
      \dimensioning{1}{begin}{middle}{1.5}[$l$];
      \dimensioning{1}{middle}{end}{1.5}[$l$];
      %%the load and their names
      %%M
      \load{2}{begin};
      \notation{1}{begin}{$M$}[above right = 10pt];
      %%G
      \load{1}{middle}[90];
      \notation{1}{middle}{$G$};
      %%F
      \load{1}{end}[-90];
      \notation{1}{end}{$F$}[below right];
      \coordinateSystem
    \end{tikzpicture}

    $M$ und $G$ seien bekannt. Gesucht ist $F$ und die Auflagerreaktionen. Freischnitt:
%    \input{virtual_displacement_free_body_diagram}
    %contains:

    \begin{tikzpicture}[trim left=(begin)]
      %the points
      \point{begin}{0}{0};
      \point{middle}{2.5}{0};
      \point{end}{5}{0};
      %%the beam
      \beam{2}{begin}{end};
      %%the load and their names
      %%A_x
      \load{1}{begin}[180];
      \notation{1}{begin}{$A_x$}[left = 30pt];
      %%A_y
      \load{1}{begin}[-90];
      \notation{1}{begin}{$A_y$}[below right];
      %%M
      \load{2}{begin};
      \notation{1}{begin}{$M$}[above right = 10pt];
      %%G
      \load{1}{middle}[90];
      \notation{1}{middle}{$G$};
      %%F
      \load{1}{end}[-90];
      \notation{1}{end}{$F$}[below right];
      \coordinateSystem

    \end{tikzpicture}

    Virtuelle Verschiebungen:

%    \input{virtual_displacement}
    %contains:
    \begin{tikzpicture}[trim left=(begin)]
      %the points
      \point{begin}{0}{0};
      \point{end}{5}{0};
      %the beam
      \begin{scope}[dashed]
        \beam{2}{begin}{end};
      \end{scope}
      %the displaced points
      \point{delta_begin}{.5}{.5};
      \point{delta_end}{5.5}{1};
      %the displaced beam
      \beam{2}{delta_begin}{delta_end};
      %virtual displacements
      \dimensioning{2}{begin}{delta_begin}{0}[$\delta y$];
      \dimensioning{1}{begin}{delta_begin}{.5}[$\delta x$];
      \draw
        [dashed] (delta_begin) -- (5.5, .5);
      %angle between the beam and displaced beam
      \coordinate (A) at (5.5, .5);
      \coordinate (B) at (delta_begin);
      \coordinate (C) at (delta_end);
      \pic[draw,
            angle radius = 45mm,
            angle eccentricity = .9,
            "$\delta \varphi$"
           ] {angle};
      \coordinateSystem
    \end{tikzpicture}

\newpage

On this page the \verb|\useasboundingbox| macro is demonstrated.

   % \input{virtual_displacement_system}
    %contains:
     \begin{tikzpicture}
     \useasboundingbox (-2,2.5) rectangle (7.5,-1);
      %%the points and their names
      %%A
      \point{begin}{0}{0};
      \notation{1}{begin}{$A$}[above = 50pt];
      %%B
      \point{middle}{2.5}{0};
      \notation{1}{middle}{$B$}[above = 50pt];
      %%C
      \point{end}{5}{0};
      \notation{1}{end}{$C$}[above = 50pt];
      %%the beam
      \beam{2}{begin}{end};
      %%the support
      \support{1}{begin};
      \hinge{1}{begin};
      \dimensioning{1}{begin}{middle}{1.5}[$l$];
      \dimensioning{1}{middle}{end}{1.5}[$l$];
      %%the load and their names
      %%M
      \load{2}{begin};
      \notation{1}{begin}{$M$}[above right = 10pt];
      %%G
      \load{1}{middle}[90];
      \notation{1}{middle}{$G$};
      %%F
      \load{1}{end}[-90];
      \notation{1}{end}{$F$}[below right];
      \coordinateSystem
    \end{tikzpicture}

    $M$ und $G$ seien bekannt. Gesucht ist $F$ und die Auflagerreaktionen. Freischnitt:
%    \input{virtual_displacement_free_body_diagram}
    %contains:


     \begin{tikzpicture}
      \useasboundingbox (-2,1.5) rectangle (7.5,-1);
      %the points
      \point{begin}{0}{0};
      \point{middle}{2.5}{0};
      \point{end}{5}{0};
      %%the beam
      \beam{2}{begin}{end};
      %%the load and their names
      %%A_x
      \load{1}{begin}[180];
      \notation{1}{begin}{$A_x$}[left = 30pt];
      %%A_y
      \load{1}{begin}[-90];
      \notation{1}{begin}{$A_y$}[below right];
      %%M
      \load{2}{begin};
      \notation{1}{begin}{$M$}[above right = 10pt];
      %%G
      \load{1}{middle}[90];
      \notation{1}{middle}{$G$};
      %%F
      \load{1}{end}[-90];
      \notation{1}{end}{$F$}[below right];
      \coordinateSystem

    \end{tikzpicture}

    Virtuelle Verschiebungen:

%    \input{virtual_displacement}
    %contains:
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      \useasboundingbox (-2,1.5) rectangle (7.5,-0.7);
      %the points
      \point{begin}{0}{0};
      \point{end}{5}{0};
      %the beam
      \begin{scope}[dashed]
        \beam{2}{begin}{end};
      \end{scope}
      %the displaced points
      \point{delta_begin}{.5}{.5};
      \point{delta_end}{5.5}{1};
      %the displaced beam
      \beam{2}{delta_begin}{delta_end};
      %virtual displacements
      \dimensioning{2}{begin}{delta_begin}{0}[$\delta y$];
      \dimensioning{1}{begin}{delta_begin}{.5}[$\delta x$];
      \draw
        [dashed] (delta_begin) -- (5.5, .5);
      %angle between the beam and displaced beam
      \coordinate (A) at (5.5, .5);
      \coordinate (B) at (delta_begin);
      \coordinate (C) at (delta_end);
      \pic[draw,
            angle radius = 45mm,
            angle eccentricity = .9,
            "$\delta \varphi$"
           ] {angle};
      \coordinateSystem
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: output of above code]

Comment: Hello @Torbjørn T.! Sorry for the delay. Thank you for your excellent answer! You provided much more greate information, than needed. It describes all I need! Thank you for `parskip`!